# Why I couldn’t use get_user_model() at import time

Tags: django, django-forms

Just as the title, I cannot import usercreationform
. The exception is model haven’t been loaded. It’s only appears in Django 1.10. There’s no such problem in Django 1.11 . I know it depends on whether get_user_model() can be called at runtime. What should I do to solve it in Django 1.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
from django.contrib.auth import(
    login,
    logout,
    get_user_model,
    authenticate,
    )
```

at the beginning of the file. Now I hope you can solve your problem :)